How can I use correctly checkboxList in Yii2?
In my Yii2 project I use the model file MultiSelect.php which contains the 2 functions below. With those functions I display a multiple select dropdown list without problem. But when I use those functions to get a multiple checkbox list I can't get the values (of the checkboxes that are already stored in the databases as array eg [black,white]) checked.
  public function getFieldInput($form, $model, $options = [])
    {
        $options['multiple'] = true;

        try {
            $values = json_decode($model->{$this->profileField->alias});
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            $values = [];
        }

        if (is_array($values)) {
            $options['options'] = [];
            foreach ($values as $value) {
                $options['options'][$value] = ['selected' => true];
            }
        }
            
 return $form->field($model, $this->profileField->alias)->dropdownList($this->getSelectItems(), $options);
       
        }
    }
    

  
    public function getSelectItems()
    {
        $items = [];
      

        foreach (explode("\n", $this->options) as $option) {
            if (strpos($option, '=>') !== false) {
                list($key, $value) = explode('=>', $option);
              
                $items[trim($key)] = Yii::t($this->profileField->language_category, trim($value));
              
            } else {
                $items[] = Yii::t($this->profileField->language_category, trim($option));
            }
            
        }

        return $items;
    }

I already changed these lines of code :
 if (is_array($values)) {
            $options['options'] = [];
            foreach ($values as $value) {
                $options['options'][$value] = ['selected' => true];
            }
        }

    return $form->field($model, $this->profileField->alias)->dropdownList($this->getSelectItems(), $options);

to:
if (is_array($values)) {
            $options['options'] = [];
            foreach ($values as $value) {
                $options['options'][$value] = ['checked' => true];
            }
        }



return $form->field($model, $this->profileField->alias)->checkboxList($this->getSelectItems(), $options);

but now I get this HTML output:
<div id="appearance-color" class="form-control" multiple="" options="{"black":{checked:true},"white":{"checked":true}">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="appearance[color][]" value="black"> Black</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="appearance[color][]" value="white"> White</label>
</div>

Instead for example:
<label><input type="checkbox" name="appearance[color][]" value="black" checked="" > Black</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="appearance[color][]" value="white" checked=""> White</label>

Any idea on how can I make it work correctly?
